# ¿Como recorrer array de objetos con atributos de tipo private en PHP?

Tags: php, poo, php7

Estoy guardando objetos creados en un array para después recorrerlos y poder mostrarlos en pantalla, al principio lo podía realizar sin problemas ya que estaba trabajando con atributos de tipo public, por lo cual acceder a ellos no era ningún problema, pero ahora estoy trabajando con get, set y con los atributos de tipo private, por lo cual me surgió la duda como puedo recorrer un array de objetos y poder acceder a los atributos de tipo private para finalmente mostrarlos por pantalla.
Adjunto el código de la clase:

```
class Persona {

    private $nombre; 
    private $apellido; 

    function __construct($nombre, $apellido)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre; 
        $this->apellido = $apellido; 
    }

    function get_nombre(){ 
        return $this->nombre; 
    }

    function set_nombre($nombre){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function get_apellido(){ 
        return $this->apellido; 
    }

    function set_apellido($apellido){
        $this->apellido = $apellido;
    }

}
```

Y ahora el codigo de la clase principal:

```
require("persona.php"); 

$persona1 = new Persona("juan", "Perez"); 
$persona2 = new Persona("Benjamin", "Torres");

$arrayPersona = array(); 

$arrayPersona[] = $persona1; 
$arrayPersona[] = $persona2; 

// print_r($arrayPersona); 

foreach($arrayPersona as $i){
    echo $i; //ERROR 
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: @BetaM Cuando los atributos los tenia de tipo públic, en el foreach simplemente imprimía un echo i->nombre por ejemplo, y me imprimía todos los nombres de los objetos que estaban en el array, ahora no puedo acceder a ellos por que están encapsulados, también intente obtenerlos los datos dentro del foreach con i->get_nombre, pero aún así me daba error y no me imprimía nada!

Comment: Si te faltó el signo de $ en la variable i puede ser por eso, por que esto: `echo $i->get_nombre();` da el resultado esperado

Answer (score 0):

¿Que error presentas exactamente?, ya que probé tú código y es funcional, solo que en el foreach agrege el llamado del método get:

```
foreach($arrayPersona as $i){
 echo $i->get_nombre()."\n";
```

}